# How can I access binary file data without loading it entirely in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file, hash, loading

I'm writing a little utility in cocoa to compute MD5, SHA-1, and other hash functions of a file. If understand correctly, at least the MD5 algorithm can be realized in such a way that I'll only need to load small portions of the file at the same time — which seems like a good idea, because I wouldn't want to occupy all the user's RAM and then some just to compute hash of a 10-Gb archive.

How can I achieve this using Cocoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSData` can memory-map a file so that the underlying OS' (Mac OS or iOS) virtual memory system automatically pages in sections of the file as needed. Use one of the `NSData` constructors with an `options:` parameter and the [`NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` or `NSDataReadingMappedAlways`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDataReadingOptions) option.

Comment: Nice. I did not know about this.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without memory mapping the file, which can be fraught, you would use `NSFileHandle` and just read data in chunks of whatever size, using `-readDataOfLength:`.

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices in cocoa:

- Memory-mapped NSData
- NSStream
- NSFileHandle

I have open source code showing ow to use a stream here: https://github.com/karelia/KSCrypto/blob/master/KSSHA1Stream.h